# override spring-data-cassandra SchemaAction

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

How would I go about overriding `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` to use my own function to create a schema. I would like to be able to set up a Cassandra instance using a cql script that I select at runtime.

I have tried to override `CassandraSessionFactoryBean.performSchemaAction()` when it is created in `AbstractCassandraConfiguration.session()`. This causes cqllib to fail with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

This seems to be related to how cqlib creates proxies: [Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223297/spring-social-superclass-has-no-null-constructors-but-no-arguments-were-given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `getStartupScripts()` in `AbstractCassandraConfiguration`.  In there, you can do anything you want to.  It's used by `CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean`'s `executeSpecsAndScripts` method (which is called in `afterPropertiesSet`).

Comment: Hmmm that might work. Would I be able to query my cluster inside of this method?

Comment: The method lets you execute arbitrary CQL scripts (as a `List<String>`).  Do whatever you'd like to in them.

Comment: This works with the slight caveat, that if I need need to any logic based on the current state of the cluster, I need to use the Datastax driver directly.